# Whether to choose the hyphen or the en dash in cases like "Anglo-Saxon England" or "The Washington-Moscow hotline"?

Tags: typography

My question is very short.

Whether I should use the en dash (U+2013) or the hyphen in cases like

> Anglo-Saxon England (Anglo–Saxon England) (a famous book by F. M. Stenton)

or

> The Washington-Moscow hotline (The Washington–Moscow hotline)

?

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks a lot. Sorry for asking this question on a wrong site.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer now on the basis that it could be considered a typesetting question, so it's not blatantly off-topic. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In English, compound adjectives like Anglo-Saxon, sun-bleached, blueish-green, or compound nouns such as bird-of-prey, mother-in-law, vice-president, etc., are always with a hyphen.

The en dash is used to replace the word "to" in things such as Washington–Moscow hotline, London–Edinburgh train, etc.  It has a different meaning from a hyphen.

Obviously different languages may have different uses for hyphens and en dashes.